# How to convert a content Uri into a File

Tags: android, file, uri

I know there are a ton of questions about this exact topic, but after spending two days reading and trying them, none seamed to fix my problem.

This is my code:

I launch the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` in my `onCreate()`

```
Intent selectIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        selectIntent.setType("audio/*");
        startActivityForResult(selectIntent, AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

retrieve the `Uri` in `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)) {
                audio = data.getData();
            }
        }
    }
```

pass the `Uri` to another activity and retrieve it

```
Intent debugIntent = new Intent(this, Debug.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("audio", audio.toString());
            debugIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(debugIntent);

Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        audio = Uri.parse((String) bundle.get("audio"));
```

The I have implemented this method based on another SO answer. To get the actual Path of the Uri

```
public static String getRealPathFromUri(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

and in the Debug activity's `onCreate()` I try to generate the file:

```
File audioFile = new File(getRealPathFromUri(this, audio));
```

This is how the error looks like:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                           at java.io.File.(File.java:262)
>                                                                           at com.dancam.lietome.Debug.onCreate(Debug.java:35)

When I run the app I get a NPE on this last line. The audio Uri, isn't NULL though so I don't understand from what it is caused.

I'd really appreciate if you helped me out.

[This is the library](https://github.com/intervigilium/libwave/blob/master/src/com/intervigil/wave/WaveReader.java) I'm trying to work with.

**Note:** I know exactly what NPE is, but even debugging I couldn't figure out from what it is caused in this specific case.

Comment: @isabsent I don't see any result I get an NPE

Comment: I see. Set breakpoint to each string in method `getRealPathFromUri(Activity activity, Uri contentUri)` and find out which string leads to NPE. I suppose `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)` throws NPE.

Comment: what do you need that `File` for? you have a `Uri`, just use it, and no, no need to pass a `String`, use `Intent#setData` instead

Comment: @pskink no I need a File, a Uri isn't working for me.

Comment: @isabsent no particular String in the method is causing the NPE it happens always in the call line

Comment: what for? why it isnt working for you? where do you want to use it? have you seen how many posts here  use that `getRealPathFromUri` method without any success?

Comment: If so, set breakpoint inside of `getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)` method in Android sources and go ahead step by step (F8 in AS).

Comment: @pskink for some paople the getRealPath seamed to work. Still how is it possible that there's no way to convert an Uri to File? It should be a pretty easy operation

Comment: simply by using `ContentResolver` API - it has methods for opening any `content://` based `Uri`

Comment: @pskink Please show me in an answer how to use it. I never worked with Files before. I'd really appreciate that

Comment: then try to read `ContentResolver` documentation, but you didnt answer my question: where do you want to use your audio `Uri`? there is a chance that you can do that even easier...

Comment: @pskink I need to use a function that has a File as a parameter. But I can't pass a file from an Activity to another. I need to pass a Uri. That's why I need to convert it later

Comment: what function? what class do you mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> pass the Uri to another activity and retrieve it

Your other activity does not necessarily have rights to work with the content identified by the `Uri`. Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent` used to start that activity, and pass the `Uri` via the "data" facet of the `Intent` (`setData()`), not an extra.

> To get the actual Path of the Uri

First, there is no requirement that the `Uri` that you get back be from the `MediaStore`.

Second, `managedQuery()` has been deprecated for **six years**.

Third, there is no requirement that the path that `MediaStore` has be one that you can use. For example, the audio file might be on removable storage, and while `MediaStore` can access it, you cannot.

> How to convert a content Uri into a File

On a background thread:

- Get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`
- Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` that you obtained from `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`
- Create a `FileOutputStream` on some `File`, where you want the content to be stored
- Use Java I/O to copy the content from the `InputStream` to the `FileOutputStream`, closing both streams when you are done

Comment: but honestly i really doubt OP needs a `File` - most 3rd party libs when they have `File` param, they also accept `InputStream` as their input - infortunately OP didnt want to say where he wants to use it...

Comment: @pskink Please check the library in the edited question. There's no input stream constructor there, only one that gets a path and a name, and another that get's the whole file. I was thinking to use the one who had the file as a parameter. And thanks CommonsWare for the great and detailed answer

Comment: @Daniele and have you seen where `mInFile` is used? only in one place: `FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(mInFile);`, so the easiest solution is just to add a new constructor that takes `InputStream`

Comment: Ok so it is an InputStream in the end. I only need to modify the constructor right? and then? what do I pass as an inputStream? The Uri itself?

Comment: @Daniele please read CommonsWare answer - he says how to get `InputStream` from your `Uri`

Comment: That's right thanks. I'll implement this this afternoon

Comment: created a new constructor with InputStream and all of this worked flawlessly thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem for Android Q, so I end up creating a new file and use input stream from content to fill that file
Here's How I do it in kotlin:

```
private var pdfFile: File? = null

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                when (requestCode) {
                    REQUEST_CODE_DOC -> {
                        data.data?.let {
                            if (it.scheme.equals("content")) {
                                val pdfBytes =
                                    (contentResolver?.openInputStream(it))?.readBytes()
                                pdfFile = File(
                                    getExternalFilesDir(null),
                                    "Lesson ${Calendar.getInstance().time}t.pdf"
                                )

                                if (pdfFile!!.exists())
                                    pdfFile!!.delete()
                                try {
                                    val fos = FileOutputStream(pdfFile!!.path)
                                    fos.write(pdfBytes)
                                    fos.close()
                                } catch (e: Exception) {
                                    Timber.e("PDF File", "Exception in pdf callback", e)
                                }
                            } else {
                                pdfFile = it.toFile()
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, i think pdfBytes will be very large for program memory if the pdf is large.
What do you think?

Answer (score -1):

Daniele, you can get path of file directly from data like below in onActivityResult():

```
String gilePath = data.getData().getPath();
```

Comment: I am checked this code for .doc file format I get real path from this.

Comment: it returns `home:test1.wav` that's not the whole path right? Because the file isn't generated correctly

Comment: you test this in emulator or in real device?

Comment: I also use this code in OnePlus 3t, I am getting correct path.

Comment: This will only work if the scheme is `file`, which is increasingly uncommon.